# Parse string to date of specific format

Tags: java, java-time

I have a string with the following format `String stringDate = "2019-04-25T07:03:17.428Z";` and I need to convert it to a LocalDateTime object of format 2019-04-25 07:03:17

I have tried with `LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` but I get this parse exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-04-25T07:03:17.428Z' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

What would be the way to convert to specific format?

Comment: Can you provide the exception that you are getting? Looks like your parse pattern is incorrect

Comment: The string you have got is in UTC (denoted by the trailing `Z`). Do you need the `LocalDateTime` to be in yout own or the user’s time zone?

Comment: @OleV.V. it can stay in UTC

Comment: @MattiaRighetti Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-04-25T07:03:17.428Z' could not be parsed at index 10
 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
 at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What you asked for (but don’t want)

```
    String stringDate = "2019-04-25T07:03:17.428Z";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

Output is

> 2019-04-25T07:03:17

It gives you what you said you wanted, but as [rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot) points out in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67625608/1366871), it does not make sense. It ignores the offset `Z` that was in your string. The offset is crucial for interpreting the date and time as a point in time. If the string had been `2019-04-25T07:03:17.428+13:00` instead, you would still have got the same output even though the string denotes a point in time that is 13 hours earlier.

The call to `truncatedTo()` gets rid of the fraction of second. If you can live with that fraction of second, leave out that call.

### What you may want instead

For a more sensible conversion:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Zagreb");
    
    Instant pointInTime = Instant.parse(stringDate);
    LocalDateTime ldt = pointInTime.atZone(zone)
            .toLocalDateTime()
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.format("Date and time in %s: %s%n", zone, ldt);
```

> Date and time in Europe/Zagreb: 2019-04-25T09:03:17

Now the time 07:03 UTC has been converted to 09:03 Central European Summer Time.

Edit: If you positively need a `LocalDateTime` in UTC, for example for a database column requiring this, you may make this fact explicit in your code in this way:

```
    LocalDateTime ldt = pointInTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toLocalDateTime()
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.format("Date and time in UTC: %s%n", ldt);
```

> Date and time in UTC: 2019-04-25T07:03:17

### What went wrong in your code?

To understand what failed for you let’s look at the exception message you got:

> Text '2019-04-25T07:03:17.428Z' could not be parsed at index 10

Index 10 is where the `T` that signifies the start of the time part is. Let’s compare to your format pattern string: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. This has a space instead of a `T` before the time part. This was the reason for the exception. If you needed to specify in the pattern that a `T` must be there, we would need to enclose it in single quotes, for example `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 2):

Your input, fundamentally, isn't an LDT. It's a ZDT - that Z is a zone (ZonedDateTime). Thus, it is not possible to convert this string *directly* to an LDT, and that's good, because that'd make no sense.

Convert it to a ZDT. Then convert *that* to an LDT. It's a single method call.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it first using ***java.time.Instant*** and then use method ***ofInstant*** of ***java.time.LocalDateTime*** example:

```
String stringDate = "2019-04-25T07:03:17.428Z";
var instant = Instant.parse(stringDate);
var localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```